# Getting permutations of an int[] removing duplicates sets

Tags: java, duplicates, integer, permutation

I have an array of integers `1<=N<=100`, How can I get permutations of this array? Array may contain duplicates, so resulting set of permutations can be duplicate, so need to get all non-duplicate permutations.

- I've found lot of snippets which would convert the `int[]` to string and perform permutations and printout, but as I hv here is integers of range `1<=N<=100`, so converting them into string would spoil integer.
- I can get all permutations with duplicates including, for final set of permutations where duplicates are removed have to check with each other to remove a duplicate or so, it so heavy process.

Is there any simpler way?

For example, `123` would give:

```
231
321
312
132
213
123
```

Similarly for `112` program would give:

```
121
211
211
121
112
112
```

So, for `n`-set of elements, permutations will be of `n!`
With duplicates in elements, would decrease tht.
I'm asking how can I remove those duplicate sets. (duplicate set of permutation arr[])

Comment: How do you generate permutations?

Comment: If you have `1, 1, 2` as input, you want `1`, `2`, `1, 2` and `2, 1` then?

Comment: permutation of elements 1,1,2 will be 121
211
211
121
112
112
Here duplicates are 211,121,112 as we have one duplicate 1 in elements

Comment: permutations for 1,1,2 would be 1,1,2 1,2,1 2,1,1. Not non-duplicate list of 3 elements total permutations will be 6.

Comment: @Shraddha i'm saying a program generates permutations in tht way, the permutations as u said, are done with human-sense. i'm asking how can i write a program to do in tht way

Comment: So, you have a program that when fed with a list of integers returns a list of permutations. e.g. for input list [1, 1, 2] the output list would be: [121, 211, 211, 121, 112, 112].

Comment: Ya, any permutation program without considering the equality of each, would result n! permutations as i gave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is acceptable to first sort the elements lexically, then you can your lexical permutation. Including an algorithm which does it for an array of int, easily modifiable to strings.

```
public static boolean permuteLexically(int[] data) {
    int k = data.length - 2;
    while (data[k] >= data[k + 1]) {
        k--;
        if (k < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    int l = data.length - 1;
    while (data[k] >= data[l]) {
        l--;
    }
    swap(data, k, l);
    int length = data.length - (k + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        swap(data, k + 1 + i, data.length - i - 1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example of how to use it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] data = { 1,2,3 };
    do {
        System.err.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    } while(Util.permuteLexically(data));
}
```

Using this with [1,2,3] you get

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

with [1,1,3] you instead get

```
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 1]
```

which is what you asked for I think.

Since the method retunes the "next" permutation in lexicographically order it is important that the elements are ordered. Starting with [3, 2, 1] you get no more permutations (compare to example above).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1563390
for 10,10,10,5,10
it would only gimme 10,10,10,10,5 -What happened to other's ?

Comment: @cypronmaya You missed my first comment that the data has to be sorted. The algorithm gives you the "next" permutation until the elements are in reverse order. Start with [5,10,10,10,10] and keep calling until the method returns false. After each call the elects in the array has been reordered.

Comment: the data[] upon each iteration changes to new values, because it is of value by reference type. During looping where generating each permutation, i wanna build up a list of those sets, as i can see here is, when i try to copy data to an arraylist each time in do loop, as array reference is stored, would make arraylist with same elements .

Comment: So, i've used Arrays.copyOf to serve the purpose, but as it takes a lot of memory, i get java oom heap error, actually i can set heapsize in local machine ,but not when i'm submitting to online compilers.
Is there anyway, where this snippet would build up a complete list by itself?

Comment: I don't follow you, The idea of this algorithm is that you should be able to start with the sorted list, permute it, do the next thing, permute again and so on until the permute returns false. You could easily wrap this method in class which stores the array internally and returns a copy of the array when requested. To store all permutations would probably not be feasible, just using the numbers 1-15 would result in 1307674368000 permutations or 75TB of ram using ints. Using byte[] instead would only take about 20TB of ram ;-) Do you really need to store all permutations?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [*Set*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of an array of *ints*, it could delete your duplications automatic.

**Edit:** @allingeek  give me an idea. More than implements your own [*Set*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) you could write a wrapper over an int and overwrite your equals and hashcode methods, finding the way where your permutations are equals. Perhaps using the numbers in order and others advise given in "Effective Java" (for equals and hashcode implementations to avoid mistakes). It could give you a better way to find your permutations in the [*Set*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). More than use expressions language as I say at first.

Comment: I'm asking to remove duplicate sets, not duplicate elements

Comment: i guess based on n! no. of permutations, for each .add call would be exhaustive upon increase of elements

Comment: Using a set is almost a good idea, but not in the way being described here.  If your permutations could be uniquely identified via some hash code (no collisions) then you could use a HashSet if you implemented the hashcode method well on your new Permutation object.  This is quite a bit of work though.  I'd rather just not generate the duplicate permutations in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You want all non-duplicate permutations of an array. The number of these, assuming each array entry is unique, Factorial(array.length), quickly becomes uncomputably large. But assuming you want to enumerate them the simplest way is to do the following :

Your problem is basically a selection problem over your alphabet (1 <= N <= 100). It does not matter if you want to select 5 of these or 500, you want to select some number, call it, x. Think of the unique elements you want to select from, those that you do not want to duplicate (this may be a proper subset of your alphabet, or not). Lay these elements out in a row. The length of this row is n. Now the selection problem of enumerating a selection of x of these can be solved as follows. Think of an n bit number, that can only ever contain n-x zeroes. To get this rank-x number, simply start from 0 and enumerate all possible numbers up to 2**n, selecting only those that have exactly x 1s (and n-x zeroes). These 1s then select x positions from the n positions of your alphabet, and each of these rank-x numbers selects a permutation for you.

If anyone knows an optimization so that you don't have to work out all the non-rank-x ones, please say so.
EDIT:
The answer, it seems, is [here](http://eusebeia.dyndns.org/epermute.html)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to remove duplicate elements is to add the contents to a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which won't allow duplicates and then add the Set back to an [`ArrayList`](http://www.lvp.com/data/java%20supplements/The%20ArrayList%20Class.pdf) as an example below.

```
ArrayList<String>al=new ArrayList<String>();

al.add(String.valueOf(arr[0]));  //Just as an example.

HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.addAll(al);
al.clear();
al.addAll(hs);
```

Comment: I'm asking to remove duplicate sets, not duplicate elements.

Comment: It depends upon the logic you're following. Use some structures like *loops* to iterate over, store elements into some other structures like arrays or collections and remove the duplicates as and when required using this method. It's the easiest way to remove duplicates I think.

Comment: removing duplicate sets ,where comparing each other internally would take time, and if N! is high, it would take ages. I'm trying to find a solution which while generating permutations itself, would remove duplicate sets

Comment: What's wrong with using a `Set` to store computed permutations. That will handle the duplicate removal part right?

Comment: Here, what @Lion suggested is to Set would remove duplicate element. I agree but we are not adding an element to it right, we are adding a computed permutation which is int[], how can set would know whether there's already an int[] of same elements? unless we hack add method by implementing our own set as jenaiz suggested

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort the array.
2. Use a nested loop where the outer loop iterates through each element in the array.  If the next element has the same value as the last, skip.  The inner loop then places that element at each position in the list.  Saving a permutation on each loop.

This will generate the permutations as well as skip repetitious permutations.

```
int[] sortedSourceArray = ...;
int last = -1;
int current = -1;
// build one permutation with the original array
buildPermutation(permutationList, sortedSourceArray);  // I'm not going to implement this for you.
for (int i = 0; i < sortedSourceArray.length; i++) {
  current = sortedSourceArray[i];
  // check if the new value is the same as the last
  if(current == last) 
    continue;
  // remove the current element from the list
  // build your permutations
  for(int j = 0; j < sortedSourceArray.length; j++) {
    // skip if its inserting the element at its original position
    if(j == i)
      continue;
    // fix the duplicates for blocks of repeated elements
    if(j < sortedSourceArray.length-1 && sortedSourceArray[j+1] == current)
      continue;
    // inject the current element at the new position
    inject(sortedSourceArray, current, j); 
    // build the permutation
    buildPermutation(permutationList, sortedSourceArray);
    // remove the current element from that position
    remove(sortedSourceArray, j);
  }
  last = current;
}
```

EDIT: Actually I think this would need to be tweaked a bit more to capture the last few cases where duplicates are generated.  That would be where a repeated element is inserted next to its same value.  I've changed the code appropriately.

Comment: Understood, but implementing could take lot of thinking. Will it be possible to provide a hack for that?

Comment: Updated with a bit of mixed real code and some unimplemented methods which should be pretty clear.  Kinda just slapped this together, so it might need some tweaking.

Comment: This is still O(n^2) but for permutation generation, I guess that's not so horrible.