# built in method to get permutations of some digits without repetition

Tags: java, permutation

is there is built in method that return all permutations of some digits without repetition

for example:

```
                int num=215;
                // i want to get (215,251,512,521,125,152)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this first link to seperate the number into its digits.
[How to get the separate digits of an int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number)

Then use this to find its permutations.
[Getting permutations of an int[] removing duplicates sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732875/getting-permutations-of-an-int-removing-duplicates-sets)

And then finally use this one to turn it back into a number. [How to concatenate int values in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674707/how-to-concatenate-int-values-in-java)

Comment: int x= 110;    
print [1,1,0]

ONLY !!!!!

Comment: These are suggestions only. You need to think for yourself to adapt these methods for you purpose. If you need help post a new questions with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The [Permutations](http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/jsc/combinatorics/Permutations.html) class could be used. The permutations are returned as 1 to n which you would have to map to your digits.